# How to merge multiple PDFs using TCPDF?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf

Merge to PDF using TCPDF I write some code form merge in CakePHP.

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//$pdf->AddPage($html, $pvalue['ClientCaseMedicalRecord']['medical_document']);

$pdf->lastPage();
//$pdf->Output(WWW_ROOT.'files/client_case_record/example_049.pdf', 'F');

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddPage(WWW_ROOT.'files/client_case_record/example_049.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->AddPage(WWW_ROOT.$pvalue['ClientCaseMedicalRecord']['medical_document'], 'all');
// $pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
$pdf->Output(WWW_ROOT.'files/client_case_record/example_019.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [FPDI](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/examples/#index-1) (example) to import PDF's in your new PDF. FPDI works with TCPDF in the same way as with FPDF.